# Hamcrest matcher for collection argument without cast

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I have a type:

```
class SomeType {}
```

And I have a method to mock with `Mockito` and `Hamcrest`:

```
class SomeService {
    public List<SomeType> doSomething(List<SomeType> producer) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to mock the `doSomething()` method if a `java.util.List` is passed and that list contains at least one specified element.
Now I use casting to make it possible to compile:

```
when(someService.doSomething(
    ((List<SomeType>) MockitoHamcrest.<List<SomeType>>argThat(CoreMatchers.hasItem(mySomeType))))
.thenReturn(emptyList());
```

But I would like to make it type safe without a cast. Is there a way to have such a check?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no way to avoid this cast, even when you change your production method parameter to `Iterable<SomeType>` as one could think this might help because `argThat` returns a `<Iterable<? super Object>>`.